# JavaScript using an array to display data

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a score system that shows per question block, I'm using PHP to retrieve the data from a table and the javascript below to calculate the score. The problem is I want several score labels underneath each question block. So clearly I need an array to make this work, but currently I'm using this line to write the data onto `document.getElementById("score_label[0]").innerHTML=""+current_score.toFixed(1);`
so this only applies to the first entry in the array. How do I make it loop through the entire array(score_label[]) and increase it's value so the code reads `document.getElementById("score_label[0]").innerHTML=""+current_score.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("score_label[1]").innerHTML=""+current_score.toFixed(1);`

this is the element javascript is writing to 
`echo "your total score: <span id='score_label[0]' name='score_board['".$score_board."']'></span>";`

if there is need for I can post the entire function but I think it's mostly my lack of knowledge on arrays that's the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly (`current_score` is the same for all elements???):

```
for (var i = 0; i < score_label.length; ++i)
    document.getElementById("score_label[" + i + "]").innerHTML=""+current_score.toFixed(1);
```

I should mention that the `id` attribute of the form `score_label[N]` may be confusing.

Comment: I agree and I doubt it holds any actual value/weight on it so I think it is safe to remove it

Comment: @JeffreyKlinkhamer: I believe you should clarify your question then, e.g. change `current_score` in the rhs of the assignments to be different in each line.

Comment: current_score is a variable defined outside my function it keeps track of the score per question block, Simply put `var current_score = 0;
function calculate_score(questions, score)`. it changes per element the problem is that it's always placed on score_label[0]

Comment: When I run the code `document.getElementById("score_label.length()")` it returns null. Does this mean my score_label isn't initialized properly? Also I've changed that line to `echo "your total score: <span id='score_label[".$score_board."]'></span>";`

Comment: It seems you are mixing up PHP and JavaScript, don't you? The first line is in JS, trying to find an element with the `id` attribute equal to the string `score_label.length()` (which, of course, does not exist.) The second one is PHP, writing HTML code into the output document.

Comment: Yes I am trying to mix these two together, is what I'm trying possible? I'm not sure how to pass the value from the second line into the javascript function..and then I need to pass the value through a form...so it's all stressful

Comment: Oh... PHP is executed on the server side, and JS is executed in the user's browser, so you can only produce JS using PHP, that will do what you need, when executed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use foreach function to loop through the whole score_label array.

[need to loop through a PHP array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663443/need-to-loop-through-a-php-array-in-javascript)